# Bootstrap 4 Tooltip -- Arrow missing

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm not sure what is missing but my tooltip is showing a box instead of showing an arrow. I try to force it by adding

```
.tooltip-arrow {
visibility: visible;}`
```

but it didn't help

***jquery***

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
$('a').mouseover(); });
```

*HTML*

```
<li><i class="ion-ios-help-outline" style="color: grey; font-size: 80%" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Test"></i></li>
```

***CSS***

```
.tooltip-inner {
background-color: #e67e22;
color: white;
font-family: 'Lato';
font-size: 80%; } 


.tooltip-arrow {
visibility: visible; }
```

Comment: Hmm... It works for me. Check [this](http://jsbin.com/ceharowoya/edit?html,css,js,output). I'm using MS Edge.

Comment: It turns out that Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 has issues with the arrow. It worked after I use Bootstrap Beta 2